# in-app billing test phone

Tags: android

I'm want to do "In-app Billing"
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html
on my app.

But it is not possible to test in-app billing in the emulator. So what phone to I need for testing? Is it only Android Dev Phone 2 and Nexus One that works?

"To test in-app billing in an application you must install the application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use the Android emulator to test in-app billing. The device you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later platform (API level 4 or higher), and have the most current version of the Android Market application installed."

Answer (score 2):

Should work on any device that has Android Market App version 2.3.4 and greater. Have written a blog for some critical issues found during setup.

http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/securityexception-binder-invocation-to-an-incorrect-interface/

Comment: Is it possible to disable in-app billing and test my application on an Android Emulator? Later on I would test on a real device. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From your quote I can't see that it is limited to a specific device. All devices running Android 1.6 or later should be possible to use in your test. Just make sure that you update the Android Market application before testing.

Answer (score 1):

Any standard android device running the latest version of the Market will do. I've seen it done on an old TMobile G1.

> The device you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later platform (API level 4 or higher)

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a free Samsung Galaxy with Android 2.1 and works fine. So any cheap android device should work.

That's the business, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this test framework : [android-test-billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing) to test the In-App billing on the emulator.
This framework was tested by the project Horer - [les horaires de RER](http://www.horer.fr).

Emulator testing should complement the real device testing, so you still have to get the device for testing before the final release to the Android Market. I advice the Samsung Galaxy Mini as the cheap phone for development.